# Iterating over arbitrary values in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/2627160), I have a query that generates a list of dates in Mysql, for example:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Month beginning                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2022-10-01                                    |
| 2022-09-01                                    |
| 2022-08-01                                    |
| 2022-07-01                                    |
| 2022-06-01                                    |
| 2022-05-01                                    |
| 2022-04-01                                    |
| 2022-03-01                                    |
| 2022-02-01                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I also have a query for calculating the number of users that have not logged in up to the end of September:

```
SET @range_end = "2022-10-01"; SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM users WHERE timestamp < @range_end) - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM logins WHERE timestamp < @range_end) AS "Not logged in";
```

This is just an example of the problem I'm trying to solve - I appreciate there are simpler approaches to this calculation.

How can I combine these queries, so the dates generated by my `Month Beginning` query are used in my user count query? Example below:

```
+-----------------+---------------+
| Month beginning | Not logged in |
+-----------------+---------------+
| 2022-10-01      |           110 |
| 2022-09-01      |           120 |
| 2022-08-01      |           130 |
| 2022-07-01      |           140 |
| 2022-06-01      |           150 |
| 2022-05-01      |           160 |
| 2022-04-01      |           170 |
| 2022-03-01      |           180 |
| 2022-02-01      |           200 |
+-----------------+---------------+
```

I've tried all sorts of joins, unions, groupings and sub queries, but can't get it to stick.

Or does what I'm trying to do fall foul of [Restrictions on Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html).

The month generation query is:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_range.timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") AS "Month beginning"
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as timestamp
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) date_range
where date_range.timestamp between '2022-02-28' and NOW() GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_range.timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your subquery as the table to select from

```
SELECT range_end AS "Month beginning", 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM users WHERE timestamp < range_end) - 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM logins WHERE timestamp < range_end)    
        AS "Not logged in"
FROM (
    select DATE_FORMAT(date_range.timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") AS range_end
    from (
        select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as timestamp
        from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    ) date_range
    where date_range.timestamp between '2022-02-28' and NOW() GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_range.timestamp, "%Y-%m-01") ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) AS date_range
```